# Accessing a Facebook Profile URL is returning Not Found (404) or redirects to Home

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a valid access token for a facebook user. (valid according access token debugger)

When calling, using that access token, to the `/me` endpoint, asking for link field, I get the information and a url like `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/<scoped_id>/`

But when I paste that url into a browser, to see the profile, <s>I get a redirect to https://www.facebook.com/4oh4</s>

As of today (2018/04/20) I get a redirect to https://facebook.com/home.php always.

Is there a way to get a link to a user profile?

Comment: I have just started getting the same issue in the last couple hours. Let's hope it's a bug and not another restriction...

Comment: now FB redirects to 'https://www.facebook.com/home.php' any app_scoped-request

Comment: A few hours ago they added this developer notice: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/

Answer (score 0):

It is (somehow) related to this bug/update: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/

Those public URLs may not work anymore in the future, i am afraid. I guess Facebook removes access to all public URLs resulting from the App platform.

Comment: The question is NOT ABOUT THE ***PICTURE*** URL. You cannot add the access_token to go to the profile page url. That is not a workaround that works.

Comment: i know, i just wrote that it is "related", that is why i did not close it as duplicate. i will test it with the profile, give me a minute.

Comment: ok, my bad, i am sorry. after so many duplicates, i did not read carefully. it IS related to the changes, but it is different because your api call actually works but the public url does not work. i updated my answer.